# How to map columns in hibernate with class attributes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My problem statement is :- I want to call a **stored procedure** in hibernate and i want to **map each column to class attributes after performing certain operations on the column returned by the  stored procedure..** As any hibernate query return a **list of object** instead of **resultset..** so how can i do it in hibernate... 
I know in spring we can do it using **jdbcTemplate Map row** concept easily but I want to use Hibernate only..

More details can be found out in my prev question:-
[Alternative to NamedParameterJDBC template row mapper in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446439/alternative-to-namedparameterjdbc-template-row-mapper-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are times we have a class, we would like to fill with data according the data returned from a query. The class is a simple POJO and not an Hibernate entity, so Hibernate won’t recognize this class. This can be done in Hibernate by using Transformers.

```
(UserActivityStat)hibernateSession.createQuery("select count(*) as totalPhotos from Photo p where p.user = :user").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserActivityStat.class)).uniqueResult();
```

In the above example totalPhotos is a property of Class UserActivityStat which is not a HibernateEntity. Using transformers you can achieve your result.

Comment: Interesting.. Can you give me more details about this.. and can i retrieve the result from procedure using this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863883/hibernate-mapping-custom-column-names-in-stored-procedure-named-query

Comment: Thanks @Pratik I am trying to implement it

Comment: Hi Pratik I tried to search more about the transformer but stuck in a situation .. I have to Perform operations on the columns depends on that i have to set the bean accordingly.. Can you help me with that..

Comment: For your situation I would suggest you have a holder dto which holds all the column values retrieved and then pass this object to a service class which will use the column values perform operations on it it and set the beans

Comment: dto is Data Transfer Object a simple POJO with getters and setters to transfer the data.